# Не создается структура проекта ItelIiJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, maven, проект

Каждый раз когда я создаю проект, не создаются некоторые папки из проекта, такие как `resource`, `main`, даже когда жму галочку "создать с главным классом".

**Структура проекта:**

[image]

Как можно это исправить?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Щелкните правой кнопкой мыши на модуль, выберите «Добавить поддержку фреймворка ...» и используйте технологию `Maven`. Это преобразует проект в [Стандартный макет Maven](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html).

Это также создаст `pom.xml` для вас, чтобы вы могли потом изменить его.