# Проблема с Intellij Idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, ide

Всем привет, проблема с IDE. Почему-то как-то странно стали располагаться папки, в смысле папка resource автоматически стала пытаться стать root папкой. Все началось как только я что-то подправила в gradle файле, но теперь это стало распространяться и при открытии других проектов. Действие mark as помогает, но при любом ребилде все становится как раньше. И еще не может найти и загрузить main класс, хотя метод main явно стоит и в конфигурации указан класс. Не пойму в чем дело, помогите пожалуйста.
Gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.0.2.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group = 'tech.viacom'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
}


ext {
    springCloudVersion = 'Finchley.BUILD-SNAPSHOT'
}

dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-config-server')
    compileOnly('org.projectlombok:lombok')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
    }
}
```

MainClass

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ConfigserviceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ConfigserviceApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: И вот еще, на папке main больше нет голубого квадрата, а раньше было и папка java & resource обе голубые и соответственно application properties не находятся, Application Context не грузится(((

Comment: Пробовали менять режим отображения папок в проекте? В настройках пробовали сбросить всё по умолчанию и посмотреть что  изменилось?

Comment: В крайнем случае можете попробовать старую добрую переустановку идеи. А вообще, можете прикрепить скриншот проблемы, я не совсем представляю её.

Comment: Попробуйте преобразовать ваш проект в мавен так, как я делаю в [этом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/829943/204920) ответе.

Comment: @KeyJibo а как здесь прикреплять скриншоты? Сорри за вопрос - нечасто здесь бываю

Comment: @RomanC а с gradle подобное чтото есть?

Comment: @Mircella Попробуйте градле, там большой список, только для этого предварительно удалите `build.gradle`.

Comment: @Mircella при создании сообщения есть кнопка с "добавить изображение", попробуйте. Вы всё ещё не решили проблему?

Comment: @KeyJibo решилось само собой, не знаю что там с idea было, но она стала сама по себе заедать и вот эта чепуха с отображением структуры проектаа, да еще почемуто все консоли стали пропадать - хотя я ничего не отключала. Потом обновила мак и все встало на свои места. Но разве это может быть связано как то?