# Ошибка java.lang.ClassNotFoundException oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jdbc, jar, classpath

После создания артефакта (`.jar` файл) в IntelliJ IDEA и при подключении к DB Oracle на RDS Amazon, выдает ошибку:

```
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
```

В самой
IntelliJ IDEA всё подключается нормально.

Comment: какой вы используете сборщик? Maven, Gradle ....

Comment: Я не знаю, просто создал проект JavaFX,(не maven)

Comment: Хорошо, вы собираете jar? какой у него размер?

Comment: Да, jar файл, размер: 3721 КБ

Comment: хм, библиотеки видимо подтянуты

Comment: @RomanC Извините, а какое отношение вопрос имеет к БД Oracle? В вашем ответе вы, например, ни одним словом её не упомянули.

Comment: @0xdb В этом вопросе речь идет о подключении к DB Oracle. В моем ответе я использовал драйвера для этой базы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть два способа добавить библиотеку в артефакт:

1. Добавьте библиотеку ojdbc7.jar в артефакт. Щелкните правой кнопкой мыши project -> properties -> выберите артефакт -> нажмите «Добавить» -> выберите «Архивы из файловой системы» -> перейдите в папку, где сохранена библиотека ojdbc7.jar -> добавьте jar -> кликните завершить -> Применить / OK. Далее, чтобы добавленный jar был виден на пути классов надо воспользоваться вот [этим](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/810249/204920) решением.
2. Мавенизировать проект, например как это описано [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/829943/204920). Если у вас нет библиотеки ojdbc7.jar в локальном репозитарии, то вы можете воспользоваться вот [этим](http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-add-oracle-jdbc-driver-in-your-maven-local-repository/) решением. Более детально вы можете найти описание [здесь](https://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-create-a-jar-file-with-maven/).

Answer (score 2):

Решение проблемы лежало в загрузке не просто jdbc в папку lib, а jdbc_g из папки oracle/product/*version*/server/jdbc/lib