# JAVA (IntelliJ IDEA) проблемы с установкой JDBC?

Tags: java, postgresql, intellij-idea, jdbc

Развернул на `localhost` сервер + поставил базу PostgreSQL. Первая на 8080 вторая на 5432.

Закидывал в Maven такие зависимости:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
  <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
  <version>9.1-901-1.jdbc4</version>
</dependency>
```

и вот так тоже пробовал.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
  <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
  <version>42.2.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Суть в том, что при выполнении

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
public class BazaTest {
public BazaTest() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
Connection connection = null;
connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
"jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres","username", "password");
connection.close();
}
}
```

Я получаю ошибку:

Если есть `Class.forname()` - тогда то, что передал в этот метод. Если убираю, то `not suitable driver for ***`.

Я так понимаю, что я не правильно подключаю как-то драва(.

P.S. Пробовал через Setting->Project Structure добавить сразу jar файлик с дравами — тоже провал.

Как дальше жить?

Вот оба стэка:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.Driver
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1309)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1138)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:291)
at testServ.doGet(testServ.java:17)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:491)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:668)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:764)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1388)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1135)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)

java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:702)
at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:228)
at testServ.doGet(testServ.java:22)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:491)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:668)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:764)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1388)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1135)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
```

Comment: postgre какой версии?

Comment: PostgreSQL-10.4-1-win64-bigsql

Comment: Тогда второй вариант.

Comment: @Suvitruf так со вторым тоже ломается(

Comment: Какая ошибка со вторым вариантом?

Comment: Если через Class.forname("org.postresql.Driver") - тогда org.postresql.Driver

Comment: @Suvitruf Что еще примечательно - я нормально подключил базу через вкладку DataBase и могу лить туда SQL. коннект проходит нормально и даже вроде подсвечивает драйвер какой-то постгресовский

Comment: `<scope>runtime</scope>` к зависимости добавляйте

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Java СlassNotFoundException oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/837000/java-%d0%a1lassnotfoundexception-oracle-jdbc-oracledriver)

Answer (score 1):

Когда вы запускаете вашу программу, то драйвера нет на пути `classpath`.

Поэтому убедитесь что все jar файлы драйверов, которые были скачаны указаны на пути `classpath`.

Как вы можете убедиться, просто посмотрите есть ли требуемые файлы в списке зависимостей в свойствах проекта IJ. Если зависимости указаны, а файл не найден, то IJ выделяет красным цветом такие файлы.

Вы также можете указать требуемые файлы в коммандной строке `java -cp .;postgresql-9.1-901-1.jdbc4.jar ваша_программа`.

Кстати `Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver")` писать не обязательно, поскольку спецификация JDBC4 предполагает загрузку класса драйвером самостоятельно.

Comment: Спасибо. А можно поподробнее про classpath. То-есть мавен криво импортит драйвер и мне нужно где-то руками прописать путь?

Comment: Отредактируйте ланчер-конфигурацию и там укажите требуемые параметры.

Comment: Извините, но я правда не понимаю, что и куда я должен указать.

Comment: Наверно вы плохо знакомы со свойствами инструмента и вам следует читать руководство [IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/documentation/).

Comment: @ДимаГуманов Вы можете также положить библиотеку с драйвером в папку `WEB-INF` прежде чем собирать артифаткт.

Comment: Спасибо помогло

Comment: В таком случае надо отметить ответ и проголосовать вверх.