# Ошибка, intellij IDEA не видит класс String и все другие классы

Tags: java, строки, классы, intellij-idea, maven

Почитал про данную ошибку, в основном пишут, что это из-за того, что не выбран project SDK и в этом духе. У меня **project SDK** выбран и не подсвечивается красным цветом(я так понимаю, что дело не в нем).

Классы с ошибками: [image]

Comment: Попробуйте - file -> invalidate cashes and restart

Comment: Ошибка осталась, только сейчас не видит только класс String.

Comment: Попробуйте запустить проект, если работает - то это глюк последней idea, я откатился на предыдущую версию, на последней невозможно работать было.

Answer (score 1):

Мне помогло следующее:

В File - Project Structure - Project - Project SDK у меня стояло значение correto-1.8 JDK, и оно подсвечивалось красным. Я поставил 11.0.6 - всё заработало.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Она не видит не только классы, но и директорию `src`, а также вложенные поддиректории с пакетами и классы, которые не установлены как исходники Java. Наверно игрались с Maven или изменяли настройки директорий вручную. Во всяком случае если используется структура директорий Maven ,то надо синхронизировать его структуру проекта с IJ. Более или менее подробно я описал об этом в следующем ответе [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/829943/204920).

> Щелкните правой кнопкой мыши на модуль, выберите «Добавить поддержку фреймворка ...» и используйте технологию `Maven`. Это преобразует проект в [Стандартный макет Maven](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html).
>
> Это также создаст `pom.xml` для вас, чтобы вы могли потом изменить его.